# How to get from Haifa to Ben-Gurion (TLV) airport on Saturday?

Tags: transportation, israel, tlv, haifa

I need to get from [Haifa](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/368182252) to the Ben-Gurion airport (codename TLV), on a Saturday, for an afternoon flight; let's say I need to be at the main terminal (Terminal 3) by 14:00.

As is well-known, however, most Israeli public transport does not run on Saturday, so - no inter-city bus or railway service. Also, suppose I don't have anyone to drive me there.

I would obviously prefer not to pay through my teeth for a private taxi, and more generally - am willing to put up with a longer ride to get a sane price.

What are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The Amal Taxi service

The Amal taxi station does group rides from Haifa to Ben-Gurion airport on Saturdays. However, there isn't a fixed regular schedule for those, and they're not super-frequent. Thus they might only have a van/taxi leaving very early in the morning, or late in the afternoon etc. They leave from He-Halutz Street 6 (in Hadar Ha-Carmel neighborhood). Their phone numbers: +972-4-8662324 , +972-4-8676444 (or 04-8662324 , 04-8676444 locally). The price should be something like 65 or 70 NIS.

[image]

[image]

---

There's a second way to use Amal, actually. They have these mini-van taxis leaving for Tel-Aviv with high frequency - usually once every 20-30 min or so; and those cost 45 min. Now, you can either look for a taxi to the airport when you arrive (say, at the Tel Aviv Savidor train & bus station compound); or hail a taxi from some taxi station, or using a mobile app like Gett - Or you might get Amal themselves to arrange something like this for you. I managed to secure this arranged for 200 NIS overall (i.e. 45 + 155).

Comment: Share taxis to Ben Gurion might be infrequent, but the ones to Tel Aviv are, from my experience. It might lengthen the trip, but going from Haifa to Tel Aviv Central Bus Station and then to Ben Gurion by private taxi (or other mode) is bound to be cheaper. I think you can get a rate of ILS 100 or just a bit more with Gett from the city to the airport.

Comment: @Ynhockey: See edit.

Answer (score 1):

**The last-ditch, overly-expensive solution:**

You can get a private taxi to take you from Haifa to Ben-Gurion airport for 350 NIS or thereabouts (e.g. [here](http://taxi-airport-israel.mozello.com/a-taxi-north-of-ben-gurion-airport/) or [here](https://www.d.co.il/80280683/24060/)).